# How to send some images in a same folder to android and how android client can decode these datastream?

Tags: php, android, image

I have implemented a cbir program using android. The basic framework is:

1. Take a picture using android camera and upload to the wamp server
2. Call the retrieval engine and store some retrieved images (for example 10 images) in folder, named './output/'
3. Php sends the result images to android for displaying.

My question is how to send these images (10 more or less) to android and how android receives and decodes these images.
On the server sider, the php script looks like:

```
<?php
  # .....

  #function for streaming file to client
  function streamFile($location, $filename, $mimeType='application/octet-stream')
  { if(!file_exists($location))
      { header ("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        return;
      }

    $size=filesize($location);
    $time=date('r',filemtime($location));
    #html response header
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');   
    header("Content-Type: $mimeType"); 
    header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');  
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Content-Length:'.($size));
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
    header("Last-Modified: $time");
    header('Connection: close');      

    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($location);

  }

  # -------------------------------------------------------
  # Main script
  # -------------------------------------------------------
  # test if the retrieved image are stored in the folder
   $processed_photo_output_path = "./output"
   $num_files = count(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/output/*.png'));

while($num_files < 10){
    usleep(100000);
}
usleep(100000);
    % send the files in the while loop.   
    $list = scandir("/output/*.png");   
    $i = $num_files;     
    for(; $i > 0; $i--){
        streamFile($list[i], $list[i], "application/octet-stream");
    }    
 ?>
```

The following code is used on the client side to receive the data. However, I find if the server sends only 1 image, it works well. If the number of images is more than 1, it crashes.

What should I do if the server pushes 10 images to the client? Any suggestions could be appreciated.

```
//get image result from server and display it in result view
    void getResultImage(HttpURLConnection conn){        
        // retrieve the response from server
        InputStream is;

        try {               
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            //get result image from server
            mResultView.resultImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            is.close();             
            mResultView.IsShowingResult = true;         
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: *sidnote:* `return` ? you mean `exit`, right?

Comment: I have figure out this question!

Comment: if you have answer of the question, please answer your question below.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out this problem. I modify my plan to send the urls of images rather than the image itself to android side. The urls are stored in mysql and is passed with Json format.